# Check if tags are empty

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have an XML file that I am parsing through BeautifulSoup. A small portion of my file is:

```
<document>
    <ad>
        <date>21-Apr-2013</date>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <date></date>
    </ad>
</document>
```

What is the fastest way to count the number of `date` elements that are not empty? Will this be faster if I convert `date` to an attribute of `ad`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one will count empty `<date>` tags:

```
sum(1 for s in soup.find_all('date') if s.text)
```

But if you really go for speed, consider some other parser, e.g. [SAX](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html)

To match attributes, use `find_all('ad', attrs={'date': ''})`

Comment: `if s.text` or `if not s.text`?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this if `date` was an attribute of `ad`?